# Phone number analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to create a custom analyzer for phone numbers using Nest from a C# app.  The following doesn't seem to do anything useful:

```
        var settings = new IndexSettings
            {
                NumberOfReplicas = maximumReplicas ?? _configuration.Value.Replicas,
                NumberOfShards = _configuration.Value.Shards,
            };

        settings.Add("index.refresh_interval", "10s");
        settings.Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10");
        settings.Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s");

        const string phoneorcodePattern = @"([^\\p{L})";  // ignore that this is silly
        settings.Analysis.Tokenizers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TokenizerBase>("phoneorpostcode", new PatternTokenizer() { Pattern = phoneorcodePattern, Flags = "CASE_INSENSITIVE" }));
        settings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, AnalyzerBase>("phoneorpostcode", new CustomAnalyzer() { Tokenizer = "phoneorpostcode", Filter = new List<string> { "lowercase" } }));

        // standard analzers
        settings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, AnalyzerBase>("keyword", new KeywordAnalyzer()));
        settings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, AnalyzerBase>("simple", new SimpleAnalyzer()));


        // field mapping stuff here...

        client.CreateIndex(_searchConnection.Settings.SearchIndexName, settings);
```

When I use CURL to test the analyzer:

```
D:\>curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/blah/_analyze?analyzer=phoneorpostcode&pretty" -d "123 456 789"
```

I get :

```
{
  "error" : "ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [phoneorpostcode]]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

Questions:

1- why the error?  the index creates just fine and I have fields using the analyzer.

2- how can I see the analyzers in the mapping?

(3- what's a good regex ?  I need to remove all white space so I can use a wildcard query.  Bonus points for answering this one :)

Cheers

Comment: For .NET compatible regular expressions try Expresso (Ultrapico) it comes with many samples.

Comment: @Jonesie can you show me the full code? you need to pass those settings to CreateIndex or UpdateSettings somehow.

Comment: @MartijnLaarman Um, there's a bunch of code after that to do the mappings (which are defined in an xml file of my own design) then I just do this: client.CreateIndex(_searchConnection.Settings.SearchIndexName, settings);  I've updated the sample above to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hacked a solution that works pretty well.

1. Remove whitespace from the phone numbers and index this.
2. Use the whitespace analyzer - NOT simple.
3. Use a wildcard query and remove whitespace from values.

I can now search for bits of phone numbers or whole phone numbers and white spaces are ignored.

e.g.
A number of 09 123 4567 can be found using '09' '09123' , '123', '12 3' etc. Works with letter also, eg: 0800 BLAHBLAH.